# How to make AngularJs ngRoute links witout #?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

Typical ngRoute link is like `mysite.com/#!/category`.SO my question is how to avoid it? How to make link look normal like `mysite.com/category` ?

Comment: you have to enable html5mode as true.

Comment: Using HTML5 mode requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application (e.g. index.html). Requiring a <base> tag is also important for this case, as it allows AngularJS to differentiate between the part of the url that is the application base and the path that should be handled by the application. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Using $location HTML5 mode Server Side](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#server-side).